# Angular / typescript compare numbers

Tags: angular, typescript, compare, logical-operators

Hi I have a problem with comparing 2 variables:

```
console.log(simulation.population == 40000000); //true
console.log(simulation.initialInfectedNumber == 5); //true 
console.log(simulation.population < simulation.initialInfectedNumber); //true
```

Both are numbers:

```
export class Seirds {
  ...
  population: number;
  initialInfectedNumber: number;
  ...
  
}
```

Can somebody explain how it works? (Because 40mln are not less than 5 :P), probably I have strings in this variables but how it is possible when this variables are numbers.

EDIT:

Get all simulation objects

service:

```
public getAllSimulations(): Observable<Seirds[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Seirds[]>(this.url + '/all');
  }
```

component method:

```
this.service.getAllSimulations().subscribe(
      value => {
        this.simulations = value;
      }
```

API response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "example name",
        "population": 40000000,
        "initialInfectedNumber": 5,
        "daysOfSimulation": 2,
        "reproductionRate": 3.0,
        "immunityTime": 60.0,
        "incubationTime": 4.0,
        "naturalDeathRate": 0.0,
        "quarantineRate": 0.5,
        "birthRate": 0.0,
        "diseaseDuration": 15.0,
        "diseaseDeathRate": 0.1,
        "reductionByRestrictions": 0.2,
        "percentageOfPopulationWhenRestrictionsBegins": 1.0,
        "daysOfRestrictions": 30.0,
        "infectiousTime": 7.0,
        "timeOfOnsetOfSymptoms": 5.0,
        "timeOfDyingFromIncubation": 8.0,
        "records": [
            {
                "susceptible": 39999995,
                "exposed": 5,
                "infected": 0,
                "recovered": 0,
                "deaths": 0,
                "quarantined": 0
            },
            {
                "susceptible": 39999993,
                "exposed": 2,
                "infected": 5,
                "recovered": 0,
                "deaths": 0,
                "quarantined": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "example name",
        "population": 40000000,
        "initialInfectedNumber": 5,
        "daysOfSimulation": 2,
        "reproductionRate": 3.0,
        "immunityTime": 60.0,
        "incubationTime": 4.0,
        "naturalDeathRate": 0.0,
        "quarantineRate": 0.5,
        "birthRate": 0.0,
        "diseaseDuration": 15.0,
        "diseaseDeathRate": 0.1,
        "reductionByRestrictions": 0.2,
        "percentageOfPopulationWhenRestrictionsBegins": 1.0,
        "daysOfRestrictions": 30.0,
        "infectiousTime": 7.0,
        "timeOfOnsetOfSymptoms": 5.0,
        "timeOfDyingFromIncubation": 8.0,
        "records": [
            {
                "susceptible": 39999995,
                "exposed": 5,
                "infected": 0,
                "recovered": 0,
                "deaths": 0,
                "quarantined": 0
            },
            {
                "susceptible": 39999993,
                "exposed": 2,
                "infected": 5,
                "recovered": 0,
                "deaths": 0,
                "quarantined": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

service component:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SeirdsService {

  private url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/seirds';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public getAllSimulations(): Observable<Seirds[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Seirds[]>(this.url + '/all');
  } 

  public addSimulation(simulation: Seirds): Observable<Seirds> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Seirds>(this.url, simulation);
  }

  public updateSimulation(simulation: Seirds): Observable<Seirds> {
    return this.httpClient.put<Seirds>(this.url, simulation);
  }

  public deleteSimulation(id: number): void {
    let endpoint = "/" + id;
    this.httpClient.delete(this.url + endpoint).subscribe();
  }
}

export class SeirdsRecord {
  susceptible: number;
  exposed: number;
  infected: number;
  recovered: number;
  deaths: number;
  quarantined: number;
}

export class Seirds {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  population: number;
  initialInfectedNumber: number;
  daysOfSimulation: number;
  reproductionRate: number;
  immunityTime: number;
  incubationTime: number;
  naturalDeathRate: number;
  quarantineRate: number;
  birthRate: number;
  diseaseDuration: number;
  diseaseDeathRate: number;
  reductionByRestrictions: number;
  percentageOfPopulationWhenRestrictionsBegins: number;
  daysOfRestrictions: number;
  infectiousTime: number;
  timeOfOnsetOfSymptoms: number;
  timeOfDyingFromIncubation: number;
  records: SeirdsRecord[];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having "problems" with simulation object and, first of all, you need to compare with `===` instead of `==` to compare values and types. Now, you have values on simulation object that represents a string and after that you're comparing string and numbers.

```
const simulation = { population: 40000000 , initialInfectedNumber: 5 };

console.log(simulation.population === 40000000); //true
console.log(simulation.initialInfectedNumber === 5); //true 
console.log(simulation.population < simulation.initialInfectedNumber); // false
```

Edit:

Typescript will show a warning if you do not use types correctly and it won't allow you to compare strings and numbers. You need to "map" your payload received from your service HTTP.

In your code, you can do something like this:

```
this.service.getAllSimulations().subscribe(
      values => { // <- I suppose this is an array with your payload and make sure pouplation and initialInfectedNumber are numbers
        this.simulations = values.map((value) => new Seird(value.population, value. initialInfectedNumber));
  }
)
```

And now you will have simulations as Seird[] but if my Seird constructor receives the correct types:

```
class Seird {
  population: number; 
  initialInfectedNumber: number;

  constructor(population: number, initialInfectedNumber: number) {
    this.population = population;
    this.initialInfectedNumber = initialInfectedNumber;
  }
}
```

Thanks to @KennyXu for the comment that indicates typescript does not check at runtime. Make sure your API returns numbers.

Comment: Ye but I cannot understand that why I have string types in numeric type variables. Look edit

Comment: Yep, Javascript can be confused sometimes that's why we try to use types (Typescript). I edited my answer, you're having problems with the way you're casting your values.

Comment: typescript does not check type at runtime. make sure your api returns number.

Comment: I added part of response from my api to post, Im pretty sure that these variables are numbers

Comment: You can try to upload the minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, maybe on stackblitz and using real code you will be able to understand better how it works.

Comment: Your solution should work, also parseInt(object.toString()) works well, but do you know why Im not getting number instead of strings from API. I added service component and full API response to edit

Comment: According to your code above, everything is OK. Maybe there is another thing that you aren't showing us that is generating the real problme.

Comment: You are right, I get some values from user input and that was a problem of string type. Thank you all.